# Not able to update the contents of the TextInput with the file i intended to

Tags: python, kivy

here is the code.
Something is missing on the TextInput. 
I have created a Filechooser application that read the contents of the file and prints on the TextInput. Just couldn't crack the last part.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

import os

Builder.load_string("""
<MyWidget>:
    id: my_widget
    Button
        text: "open"
        on_release: my_widget.open(filechooser.path, filechooser.selection)

    TextInput:
        id: input_text
        text: ??????

    FileChooserListView:
        id: filechooser
        on_selection: my_widget.selected(filechooser.selection)
""")

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    def open(self, path, filename):
        with open(os.path.join(path, filename[0])) as f:
            print (f.read())
            contents=f.read()
            MyWidget.input_text.text=contents


    def selected(self, filename):
        print ("selected: %s" % filename[0])


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

import os

Builder.load_string("""
<MyWidget>:
    id: my_widget
    input_text: input_text
    Button
        text: "open"
        on_release: my_widget.open(filechooser.path, filechooser.selection)

    TextInput:
        id: input_text
        text: '??????'

    FileChooserListView:
        id: filechooser
        on_selection: my_widget.selected(filechooser.selection)
""")

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    def open(self, path, filename):
        with open(os.path.join(path, filename[0])) as f:
            contents=f.read()
            self.input_text.text=contents


    def selected(self, filename):
        print ("selected: %s" % filename[0])


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

There were three errors.

In the kivy code you need to add id of your text_input at the top level:

```
import os

Builder.load_string("""
<MyWidget>:
    id: my_widget
    input_text: input_text # NOTE THIS LINE

    TextInput:
        id: input_text
        text: '??????'
""")
```

You shouldn't use `MyWidget.input_text.text=contents` because `MyWidget` is a class name, not the instance you're working on. Use `self.input_text.text=contents`

And finally after you call`print(f.read())` you cannot read from the file anymore unless you rewind it so next line `contents=f.read()` will result with empty `contents` variable.

Also `TextInput.text` needs to be quoted but I assume you know that.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly, i just have a doubt why i need to add id of  text_input at the top level. Please clarify this.

Comment: This is because  `MyWidget` has no `input_text` property unless you declare it. The fact there's a nested widget inside  with id of such value doesn't change this. If you don't like this you can use `ids` instead, as described in the [documentation](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#accessing-widgets-defined-inside-kv-lang-in-your-python-code). Such is the design of the framework.